# Canvas draw in functions

Tags: javascript, canvas

I had a working canvas script in my script, but I decided to move them into functions and prototypes to make it easier to read the code and easier to expand. Now I have no image at all.

This is the code that runs when the the site is loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Set width and height of canvas
    var width = $(document).width();
    var height = $(document).height();
    $("#MKslide").css({"width":width+"px","height":height+"px"});

    slideShow = new SlideShow(width, height, "2d");
    slideShow.LoadNextSlide(null);
    slideShow.NextSlide();
});
```

I create the canvas in the SlideShow constructor.

```js
function SlideShow(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, dimension){
    //Create canvas
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("MKslide");
    this.canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    this.canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext(dimension);
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.onload = function(){
        this.context.drawImage(this.image,0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    };

    this.currentSlide;
    this.nextSlide;
}
```

Then I just change the image with this function.

```js
SlideShow.prototype.NextSlide = function(){
    this.currentSlide = this.nextSlide;
    this.image.src = this.currentSlide.data;
}
```

The variable `this.nextSlide` is populated from an Ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `image.onload` function, `this` refers to the image object and not to your Slideshow object.

So your `this.image` inside the .onload is equivalent to `Slideshow.image.image` which is `undefined`.

Instead:

```
function SlideShow(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, dimension){

    // create a self reference for use in image.onload
    var that=this;

    //Create canvas
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("MKslide");
    this.canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    this.canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext(dimension);
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.onload = function(){
        // Here inside the image.onload...
        // ... "that" is your SlideShow object
        // ... "this" is the image object
        that.context.drawImage(this,0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    };

    this.currentSlide;
    this.nextSlide;
}
```